# Is it possible to arrange handshakes in this way?

Tags: graph-theory, self-learning, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

I am reading Eulerian graphs from [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://home.iitk.ac.in/%7Earlal/book/mth202.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjn8Pq-h7n0AhVKzTgGHasjCYsQFnoECB8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1ycsenP4rdL2ltBiXeUTRk) pdf. In page 210, exercise 9.5.7,  I am stuck at following problem.

> Each of 8 persons in a room has to hand shake with every other person as per the following rules:(a) The handshakes should take place sequentially.
> (b) Each handshake (except the first) should involve someone from the previous handshake.
> (c) No person should be involved in 3 consecutive handshakes.

> Is there a way to sequence the handshakes so that these conditions are all met?

What I understand that is we have to convert this problem into graph theoretical notion and then it may be easy to solve. So I consider each person as a vertex and each hand shake as an edge.

Given that each has to shake hands with every other person, the graph has to be complete graph of ordet $8$ - $K_8$. We have to traverse $K_8$ such that the above conditions are satisfied.

I think that the condition (a) implies that no two hand shakes will happen simultaneously and this is what enables us decide to traverse the $K_8$.

But here traversing little different than Eulerian path or Hamiltonian. If I have vertices $a,b,c$ then I can go from $a$ to $b$. Now I have an option to go to $c$ from $a$ or $b$ because of condition (b). But I can not traverse back from $b$ to $a$ because traversing through an edge means a handshake, so if person has to have two consecutive handshake then I have to go to $b$ then Again jump to vertex $a$ and then go to $c$.

I am not able to proceed further.  What can I do?

Comment: You seem to have the correct idea. You just need to prove that such a sequence of handshakes truly corresponds to an Eulerian path. How can we set that up EG How does condition (c) come in?

Comment: @CalivinLin But in EG, each edge is traversed once, but here the condition (b) implies we can jump or we should traverse an edge twice. So I am trying to convert the above problem into the context of EG.

Comment: How can we set up the mapping of a handshake to a path (that's hopefully eulerian)? As an example, with 5 people, a valid series of handshakes is A-B, then B-C, then C-D, then D-E, then A-E, A-C, C-E, B-E, B-D. What path does that correspond to (hopefully there's a natural choice)? Does any such valid series of handshakes always lead to a path? Why, or why not?

Comment: I recognise that your series of handshake is a Eulerian tour in $K_5$. I think no such tour is possible in K_8 since all vertices have odd degree so that we have to use condition (b) and (c).

Comment: Right, so the work is to demonstrate that such a series of handshakes must map to a Eulerian path (which is yet to be done). Then since we know that there is no Eulerian path on $K_8$, hence no series of handshakes is possible.

Comment: @aschepler That violates condition (c).